# How to make not easy to guess unique user id?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

I able to add users to room but users have number that is easy to guess. Can I have easy add users with not easy to guess id number?

Entity is

```
@Entity public class EntityUser {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    long userId;
    String userName;
}
```

Dao is

```
@Dao
public interface DaoUser {

    @Insert
    long insert(EntityUser entityUser);
}
```

Database is

```
@Database(entities = {EntityUser.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class UserDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    abstract DaoUser daoUser();

}
```

I use

```
    userDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(this,UserDatabase.class,"user.sqlite")
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .build();

    EntityUser user1 = new EntityUser();
    user1.userName = "Pandas";
    long user1id = userDatabase.daoUser().insert(user1);
    user1.userName = "Ellies";
    long user2id = userDatabase.daoUser().insert(user1);
```

I get 1 then 2.

I tried no autoGenerate but got Unique constraint error.

Comment: I would advice you to keep the database-generated id private, i.e. not use it externally. Rather, generate a second, unique id to use externally, e.g. a `UUID`. This can be generated in Java and should be hard enough to guess.

Comment: @Turing85 thanking you for saying, I use MikeT answer as UUID take more space and more slow way. Private not worry about as SQLite on device not cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use UUID.

```
@Entity public class EntityUser {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    long userId;
    String objectId;
    String userName;
}
```

And then when you generate an object you can do it like this:

```
EntityUser user1 = new EntityUser();
user1.userName = "Pandas";
user1.objectId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Comment: Thankyou, after looking at other answer I did that. Sorry I cant vote up.